# C++ malloc(): memory corruption

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I am currently going through a fibonacci practice problem on hackerrank and am having a malloc memory corruption error. This is the link to the problem I am doing:

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/programming-interview-questions/challenges/fibonacci-returns/

Input is 0-10, each number separated by a new line.
For each input, the value at that point in the sequence is printed. It works for small inputs, but after 6 it gets the malloc error. It doesn't seem that the size of the sequence is an issue either, just how many are done in succession.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<int> bigFib(1);

int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
    int x;
    while(cin >> x){
        if(bigFib.size()-1 >= x){
            cout << bigFib[x] << endl;
        }
        else{
            vector<int> fib(x);
            fib[0] = 0;
            fib[1] = 1;
            for(int j = 2; j <= x; j++){
                fib[j] = fib[j-1] + fib[j-2];
            }
            bigFib = fib;
            cout << fib[x] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am pretty new to C++ and can't find the problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're probably writing to memory that is out of your bounds.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `vector<int> fib(x)` allocates a vector of `x` elements indexed `0..x-1`. Your loop termination condition is `j <= x` which means that once you will try to do `fib[x]`

Comment: `if(bigFib.size()-1 >= x){` might be more clearly expressed as `if(x < (bigFib.size() - 1)){`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create `std::vector` of size N, you can access elements with index [0, N-1] - which is N elements. You create vector of size `x` and in your loop:

```
  for(int j = 2; j <= x; j++){
     fib[j] = fib[j-1] + fib[j-2];
  }
```

and in this statement

```
  cout << fib[x] << endl;
```

you try to access element with index equal to `x`, which is UB. If you do need to access index `x` create vector with at least `x+1` size

Answer (score 0):

In `vector<int> fib(x);` you declare a `vector<int>` that has `x` elements. Those elements are `fib[0]` through to `fib[x - 1]`. However, in `for(int j = 2; j <= x; j++){ fib[j] = ...` you assign to an element out of bounds.

Imagine if `x` is 1, then you'd expect your `fib` vector to contain only one element: `fib[0]`... yet your loop is assigning to `fib[1]`. Problem? Yup.

I reckon `for(int j = 2; j <= x; j++){` should probably be `for(int j = 2; j < x; j++){`...

... and `cout << fib[x] << endl;` should be `cout << fib[x - 1] << endl;`